# How is the mac os executable bit preserved in Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, permissions

I have two Macs, and a shared folder on a third Windows computer. If I do something like this:

1. Copy an executable console application (not a .app file - a single file which is executable) from Mac 1 to Windows machine
2. Zip executable on Windows machine
3. Copy new zip file to Mac 2 and unzip

The file that comes out of the zip file is still executable. How is the "executable-ness" nature of that file preserved, given that windows permissions system is totally different and doesn't really have the concept of executable files?

Comment: Are you trying to write an unzip program?

Comment: We're porting our app to the mac, and it uses a 10+ year old compression library that we need to retain for backward compatibility. Currently the executable flag is lost if something is compressed in Windows and then uncompressed on the mac. Switching compression libraries is not an option, for legacy reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OSX Apps are folders, not files. When copying folders to a file system, that doesn't have executable bit representation, OSX creates hidden files for the missing attributes. Zipping the App is zipping a folder, including its hidden subfolders. On copy back, OSX will recreate the missing properties from the hidden files.

These hidden folders are called ._.OriginalName

**EDIT**

After quite extensive discussion in  the comments sections, here is a bit of info about simple executable files (execute permission set) as opposed to *.app folders (native OSX applications)

- Ofcourse OSX honours the executable permissions, (set and unset)
- Copying a file to a file system, that does not have a concept of an executable permission (most prominently FAT formated USB sticks), then copying it back **after a rename on another OS** leaves OSX with the dilemma of whether to see the file as executable or not - the `._.OriginalName` metadata store is decoupled from the file by the rename
- OSX solves this dilemma by setting the permissions to 700 or 777, thus making every file executable

Comment: I'm not sure what "folders" has to do with it, but yes Mac resource forks and attributes are stored as hidden files when stored on a filesystem that doesn't support them.

Comment: I'm talking about an executable console application - not an app. It's just a single file with no "Show Package Contents" option on the right-click menu.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I was talking of OSX Applications (such as "drag into Applications folder and it will work") - I did not get, that the OQ was about a single executable file.

Comment: @Colen the concept still holds: If you zip it including a folder, the info will be there. If you zip it with the OSX Utility, it will be there.

Comment: I don't think "storing them as hidden files" explains it. If that was the case, if I copied the file to another folder in windows, changed its name, then copied it back, the executable flag should be lost, shouldn't it? And yet it is not.

Comment: I do not know (and do not want to pretend to know) every detail about that, but I suspect it to be more complex than just the file name. Try copying the file to FAT32-formated Volume (USB STick?) on the windows side to make sure the hidden files are not implemented as alternative data streams in NTFS compatibility, delete all hidden files from the folder (on the USB STick), then rename file and folder and copy back. Post your results, this might be interesting.

Comment: I copied the file to a FAT32 USB stick, no other files appeared. Renamed and copied it back, and it's still executable. I also copied it and copied the copy back, and it was also executable.

Comment: Turns out, OSX does **not** preserve the executable attribute on FAT: I just created a text file on my Desktop (644), copied it to a FAT file system, renamed it there, copied it back. The copy now has 777. This means, that the executable attribute is set, not preserved, if the hidden attribute store is inaccessible. You might want to repeat your experiment with a **not** executable file, I bet it will be executable after the copy-rename-copyback cycle.

Comment: Eugen, I think you're right - it looks like when you copy a file back from windows, it just sets it to rwx------ permissions, regardless of what the original permissions were. I didn't test it originally with a non-executable file, so I assumed it was doing something clever when it wasn't. :( If you edit the answer to show that, I'll accept it. Thanks!